# How to detect BT headset in android

Tags: bluetooth

I refer code from this [Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html).

They have mentioned that only Android 3.0 and above support the `BluetoothHeadset` and `BluetoothProfile` classes.

Then how can we can detect the BT headsets using or whithout using that classes?

Comment: Development questions are off-topic here as mentioned in the [FAQ](http://android.stackexchange.com/faq#what-about-other-android-related-questions). I've voted this to be moved to Stack Overflow, which deals with software development.

Answer (score 2):

You can detect the headset using the class [`android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html), specifically `getBluetoothClass()`, which returns a [`BluetoothClass`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass.html) object. You can then call `getDeviceClass()` and compare it to the constants defined in [`BluetoothClass.Device`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass.Device.html).

These are available starting from API level 5 (Android 2.0).